# Resize map after load in html

Tags: html, angularjs, typescript

I am using angular 2 to display a basic page that has a google 'my map' show in a modal.

```
<iframe id="map" class="center" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1uReFxtB4ZhFSwVtD8vQ7L3qKpetdMElh&ll=51.096412867708054%2C0.240690000000086&z=11" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

The problem is when it loads it is not centered or zoomed as it should be. There are a few answers on stack overflow saying that the map needs to be resized after opening and it will be fine. Is there a way to do this in html?

I can find a way to do this in typescript either?

Answer (score 0):

You can zoom the map from the URL it self. For an example

This is your default url:
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1uReFxtB4ZhFSwVtD8vQ7L3qKpetdMElh&ll=51.096412867708054%2C0.240690000000086&z=11

If you change last parameters to 15, it will zoom more.
https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1uReFxtB4ZhFSwVtD8vQ7L3qKpetdMElh&ll=51.096412867708054%2C0.240690000000086&z=**15**

Also try this snippet to resize and align your map accordingly. You can do . it with html and css it self without using typescript.

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

#map {
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0 none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <iframe id="map" src="https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/embed?mid=1uReFxtB4ZhFSwVtD8vQ7L3qKpetdMElh&ll=51.187741465291936%2C-0.009248964843663998&z=11" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: This isnt working on my modal, still doesnt center the link and im struggling to get the map to fit the width responsively

Comment: checn now, i did some adjustments

Comment: Thanks, the map width is perfect but the markers still arent centering. I think its because it is a modal popup

Comment: map centering should be fine when you directly put it to your webpage. Here it is set to the small screen first and then when you go to full page, it is not adjusting, because it is an iframe

Comment: Its isnt centering correctly on the iframe view in the modal at the moment, the page is here for more context https://scottandviki.co.uk

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_google_map_4 Check this out

Comment: Hey, i checked your edited answer but no luck, im having more luck using the link you pasted but struggling to get the view to show on load as it only works when resized which is odd